# How to redirect to client URL from node js hosted on different server?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, paypal-rest-sdk

I have a web application with client in Angular2 and server REST API in node js with express, both hosted on separate servers. Trying to integrate nodejs with PayPal with node-rest-paypal SDK. The problem is how do I redirect back to client once payment is completed. Below is the flow I am following.

1. user clicks on Pay button
2. client app sends pay info to server
3. server app creates PayPal payment and receives PayPal url
4. server app sends PayPal url back to client app
5. client app uses that url and redirects user to PayPal
6. user completes/cancels payment on PayPal website
7. PayPal returns back to configured return url i.e. to server app
8. server app executes/cancels payment and saves info in the DB
9. how to redirect from server back to client?

Return and cancel URLs are configured to redirect to node server.

One thing I could think of is to send push notification to client with help of node socket.io. But I am not sure, if that is the only and best way to tackle this problem. Please guide me in the right direction, even if I am missing some basic thing here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hope you have checked this out https://devblog.paypal.com/building-a-web-app-with-node-js-the-paypal-sdk/

Comment: The samples on devblog.paypal.com and most other blogs demonstrates UI and backend both hosted on same servers. Mine is on different servers.